# C++ создать приложение, которое меняет яркость экрана в зависимости от времени на компьютере (чтобы ночью не было ярко)

Tags: c++, время

Возникла идея такого приложения, однако не знаю как такое сделать. Нашел в интернете код , но при его запуске вылазит [image: введите сюда описание изображения] (у меня ноутбук)

Сам код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    HRESULT hError = 0;
    DWORD error = 0;
    HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
    if (hMonitor)
    {
        DWORD MaxBrightness, MinBrightness, CurrentBrightness;
        PHYSICAL_MONITOR phm[1];
        if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, 1, phm))
        {
            if (GetMonitorBrightness(phm[0].hPhysicalMonitor, &MinBrightness, &CurrentBrightness, &MaxBrightness))
            {

                time_t currentSeconds = time(NULL);
                tm* timeInfo = localtime(&currentSeconds);
                UINT currentHours = timeInfo->tm_hour;
                DWORD NewBrightness = 0;
                if (currentHours <= 6 || currentHours >= 22)
                    NewBrightness = round(MaxBrightness / 2 / 2);
                else if (currentHours > 6 && currentHours <= 12)
                    NewBrightness = round(MaxBrightness / 2);
                else
                    NewBrightness = 80;
                SetMonitorBrightness(phm[0].hPhysicalMonitor, NewBrightness);
                cout << "[INFO] Old brightness: " << CurrentBrightness << endl;
                cout << "[INFO] New brightness: " << NewBrightness << endl;
            }

            else
                error = GetLastError();
            hError = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
            cout << "[ERROR] Cannot get monitor brightness!!! - Error code: " << hex << hError << "\n";
        }

        else
        {
            error = GetLastError();
            hError = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
            cout << "[ERROR] Cannot get physical monitor!!! - Error code: " << hError << "\n";
        }



    }

    else
        cout << "[ERROR] Cannot get monitor handle!!!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: это не ошибка. Это просто в режиме отладки студия удерживает консоль, что бы Вы увидели, что там написало. Иначе она бы просто появилась на долю секунды и пропала (даже здесь на сайте много много вопросов как этого избежать)

Comment: Пользуйтесь отладчиком, отловите строку хотя бы где падает.

Comment: Ваше приложение не будет менять яркость в "риал-тайме", что бы оно работало "приближённо" как в реал-тайме, его нужно хотя бы там допустим через планировщик запускать принудительно раз в час, допустим. Тогда можно будет спустя сутки сделать вывод - работает или нет.